# Restrict access via link

Tags: laravel, middleware

I have a question

I have a personal report section on the site I wrote with Laravel

This report shows everyone like the following address

Site.Com/dashboard/report/1

Which is an id

Now I want if the user does not have the role of admin, even in the link / 2, do not show him anything and go to the previous page
Now in the show, it's ok, but they link manually, it's not like that, what should I do?

Comment: I assuming you using laravel 8.x, see the documentation, you can use a middleware in wich you can pass a role, and only the user with the specific role can access the route.
Here the link to Laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#main-content

Comment: I highly recommend using https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction  Lots of good methods to use in this for every permission need.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to achieve this. If you just want to protect one specific routes you can restrict function in help and add use this function in your controller this is the simplest way to achieve this

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // get role id by auth id
        $roleId = 1; // This is the sould be actual ID from database table
        $user = Auth::user()->role($roleId);

        if($user != null)
        {
           // Show report
        }else{
            // redirect to unauthorize route
        }

    }
}
```